How to fix "error setting owner of a.s to uid 0 and gid 0" without sudo
This is related to another question on logrotate  qs1. When running the command logrotate  /etc/logrotate.d/test, I am also getting a error: error setting owner of /var/lib/logrotate/status.tmp to uid 0 and gid 0: Operation not permitted error. The answer in the other question said that this issue can be fixed using the sudo command sudo logrotate /etc/logrotate.d/test . Is there a way to fix this without the sudo access? Can I avoid setting the owner to uid 0 and gid 0?

You cannot run logrotate as an ordinary user and have it act as if it's being run by the system.
What you can do, though, is to use logrotate to manage your own log files. For this you need to provide your own configuration file and your own state file. (These are shown in the documentation, man logrotate.)
Example
# Configuration directory
logconfdir="$HOME/.config/logrotate"
mkdir -p "logconfdir"

# Create default logging configuration
cat >"$logconfdir/config" <<'EOF'
# Per-user log rotate configuration file
#
compress
delaycompress
weekly
notifempty
missingok
create
rotate 6
maxage 180

".*.log" {
        # monthly
        # rotate 3
}
EOF

# First rotation
(
    cd "$HOME" &&
    logrotate -v -s "$logconfdir/state" "$logconfdir/config"
)

You should put the logrotate command into your crontab, so it runs daily, weekly, whatever.
